# How to determine query execution based on the existence of '2' when there is a '1' in the array

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a data_type table and a data table. The column structure is as follows.

```
data_type    data
=========    ====================
id | type    type_ID | count
---------    --------------------
 1 | a             1 | 50
 2 | b             2 | 100
 3 | c             3 | 30
```

In data_type, types 'a' and 'b' are sets, and they must be added to the data table at the same time, and only one of them cannot be entered.

If typeId 1 comes in, 2 should also come in, and if 1 comes in but 2 doesn't, we want it to fail.
If neither 1 nor 2 is entered, it succeeds. Conversely, if 2 is entered and 1 is not entered, it also fails.
In other words, typeId 1 and 2 are unconditional sets and you need to add two rows at the same time.

For example

```
INSERT INTO data (typeId, count)
VALUES (1,50), (2,90) <- O

INSERT INTO data (typeId, count)
VALUES (1,50), (3,100) <- X
INSERT INTO data (typeId, count)
VALUES (1,50) <- X
```

Can I use triggers? Or should I find the value in the array and check it with an if statement?

If I could use a trigger, I'd like to know how.

Below is my current query.
DAO.js

```
const createData = async(userId, a1, a2, typeId, count) => {
  await myDataSource.query(
    `INSERT INTO a (user_id, a1, a2)
  VALUES(?,?,?)`,
    [user_id, a1, a2]
  );

  const typeAndCount = typeId
    .map((type, index) => `((SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()),${type},${count[index]})`)
    .join(",");

  const data = await myDataSource.query(
    `INSERT INTO data (a_id ,type_id, count)
  VALUES ${typeAndCount}`
  );
  return data;
};
```

I've been wasting too much time. I need help

Comment: Question is confusing in one sentence you say a and b are must be inserted at the same time and in the next sentence you say If typeId 1 comes in, 2 should also come in , do you really care about the typeid? would 1/a 2/c 3/b be valid of does typeid for b always have to be 1 more than a or the next in sequence?

Comment: You are asking sql to read ahead on a bulk or single row insert to verify that the insert can be done based on some rule only known to you. SQL cannot do this - a trigger cannot parse the entire NEW. temp table as it operates on a row by row basis ,your front end needs to parse the inserts to see if they match your requirement.

Comment: You could perhaps throw everything into a staging table in your db and verify that before posting to the final table.